# Can you automate spatial Index creation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am learning the mongodb and try out some commands. My normal routine is this: create a collection, import data to collection, then create a spatial index like so:

`db.collection.createIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } )`

If I append more data, do I need to run this again to create spatial index? The automaticalIndex is not set when I create the collection.

Also, can this be automated, say when using the mongoimport command by adding a flag or something to add spatial index? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like there is no need to run the create spatial index again when inserting new data to an existing collection. I was doing this in a linux terminal. Perhaps it can be automated with pymongo...will need to look into that how to add a spatial index when creating a collection.